# How do we define $\sin(\theta)$ or $\cos(\theta)$

Tags: geometry, functions, trigonometry

On the interval $[0,2\pi]$, how do we define either sine or cosine? Obviously if we have one, the other is straight forward to generate as a phase shift of the other one.

To expand a little, we know what properties we want these functions to satisfy: $2\pi$-periodic, max/min of $1/-1$, $2$ zero crossings, alternating sign and function for derivatives. But the behavior near maxima/minima and zero crossings seem difficult to define without resorting to preexisting information about derivatives of the functions; for example, how fast should cosine level off as it goes to $\frac{\pi}{2}$?

Obviously one way to define these is just to find a Taylor Series which exhibits these characteristics, but it feels like there should be a more intuitive or geometric way.

One method I thought of was to define linear distance around the unit circle as a function of time, $f:[0,2\pi] \to [0,2\pi], t \mapsto t$, and then try to extrapolate the x and y coordinates (and therefore sine/cosine values) from the position on the circle. I'm not exactly sure how I would go about doing this, short of using sine and cosine themselves, in which case I suppose I've found a definition?

It also seems that there should be some way to at least define sine or cosine from $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ this way using the Pythagorean Theorem and some differentials to convert between linear/angular velocity (since they are the same in this case) and position, in which case it seems straight forward to extend this to the rest of the function.

Comment: You could define them in terms of solutions to $\dot{x} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} x$. A little work shows the solution is periodic.

Comment: @copper.hat, with the proper initial conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways of defining sine and cosine, one of which is by their respective Taylor series. Another way of defining say sine, is as the unique solution to the differential equation $y''=-y$, $y(0)=0$, $y'(0)=1$. Then we can define cosine to be its derivative.